# How to find the laplace transform of the function $f(t)= \sqrt{t}\sin(t) $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I would like to ask on how to find the laplace transform of the function

$f(t)=\sqrt{t}\sin(t)$

when i seached on wolframmath it seems that the answer used a gamma function and has a sine of arctan of something.

I would like to know the steps in finding the laplace transform of this function. Thank you so much.

Comment: $$\mathcal {L}(\sqrt{t} \sin t) = \int_0^{\infty } \dfrac{\sqrt{t} \sin (t)}{e^{s t}} \, dt$$ Can you solve that integral?

Comment: Expanding on @Moo 's comment, use $e^{\iota t} = \cos(t)+\iota \sin(t)$ and treat the imaginary unit $\iota$ purely as a constant, maybe?

Comment: This formula: $$\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{p^{n+1}} = \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-pt} \ dt,$$ may be helpful.

Comment: Expressing sine in terms of the exponential function gives
$$\mathcal L[t \mapsto f(t) \sin t](s) =
\frac {\mathcal L[f](s - i) - \mathcal L[f](s + i)} {2 i}.$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\left\{\sqrt{t}\sin{(t)}\right\}
&=\int_0^\infty\sqrt{t}\sin{(t)}e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\Im{\left(\int_0^\infty\sqrt{t}e^{-(s-i)t}\mathrm{d}t\right)}\\
&=\Im{\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{\sqrt{s-i}}e^{-u^2}\frac{2u}{s-i}\mathrm{d}u\right)}\\
&=\Im{\left(2(s-i)^{-3/2}\int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\right)}\\
&=\Im{\left(2(s-i)^{-3/2}\left(\left[-\frac12ue^{-u^2}\right]_0^\infty+\frac12\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\right)\right)}\\
&=\Im{\left((s-i)^{-3/2}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\mathrm{d}u\right)}\\
&=\Im{\left(\left(|s-i|e^{i\arg{(s-i)}}\right)^{-3/2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\Im{\left(\left(\sqrt{s^2+1}\cdot e^{-i\arctan{(1/s)}}\right)^{-3/2}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2(s^2+1)^{3/4}}\Im{\left(e^{i\frac32\arctan{(1/s)}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\sin{\left(\frac32\arctan{(1/s)}\right)}}{2(s^2+1)^{3/4}}\\
\end{align}

Comment: What does the I of the integral mean

Comment: Imaginary part?

Comment: @why The imaginary part function is typically denoted by $\Im{(z)}$ or $\text{Im}(z)$. In fact the MathJax `\Im` produces $\Im$.

Answer (score 0):

A different and tempting solution , which I ***warn is not correct***, and which requires some additional work is to use fractional derivatives.

Using the Differential of the Transform formula

$\mathscr{L}\{t^nf(t)\}=(-1)^n\frac{d^n}{ds^n}f(s)$

Put $\sqrt{t}=t^{1/2}$ and $n=1/2$

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}\{t^{1/2}\sin t \}=(-1)^{1/2}\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{ds^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{s^2+1}
\end{equation}

The fractional derivative of the fraction can be made with the forms:

\begin{array}
fF(s)=(s^2+1)^{-1}\\
\frac{d}{ds}(s^2+1)^{-1} = -2s(s^2+1)^{-2 }\\
\frac{d^2}{ds^2}(s^2+1)^{-1}= 8s^2(s^2+1)^{-3} \\
\frac{d^3}{ds^3}(s^2+1)^{-1}=-48s^3(s^2+1)^{-4}\\
\frac{d^4}{ds^4}(s^2+1)^{-1}=384s^4(s^2+1)^{-3} \\
\frac{d^n}{ds^n}(s^2+1)^{-1}=(-1)^n\cdot2^nn!s^n(s^2+1)^{-n-1}
\end{array}

Let $n=\frac{1}{2}$

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{ds^{\frac{1}{2}}}\frac{1}{s^2+1}=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}2^\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)!s^\frac{1}{2}(s^2+1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}=-i\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{s}}{2(s^2+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{equation}

multiply then with $(-1)^{1/2}$ from the overall formula at top and we get:

\begin{equation}
\mathscr{L}\{t^n\sin t\}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{2}\sqrt{s}}{2(s^2+1)^\frac{3}{2}}
\end{equation}

However, since the result is NOT correct, I invite anyone to comment or suggest correction.